# how do i remove the decimal point values from the array values?

Tags: angular, highcharts, ionic3

I am trying to show values in the chart but my array values are in decimal points, 
i need to remove them, any help?

`this.grapcalories = this.calories[0].calories;`

The values are in this variable.

Comment: this.grapcalories  is your array contains the decimal values?

Answer (score 1):

> You can use `Math.trunc()` or `Math.round()`.

I think `Math.trunc()` is more right here as it just eliminates the decimal value. `Math.round()` does the round of the value.

```
this.grapcalories = this.calories[0].calories.map(item => {
    return Math.trunc(item);
})
```

Comment: Right now its getting round off, how do i make it to 2 decimal points ?

Comment: Do like this: Math.round(3.9923 * 100) / 100 => 3.99 (Round Of) for upto two decimal point

Answer (score 1):

You can also set `valueDecimals: 0` to display values without a comma:

```
tooltip: {
    valueDecimals: 0
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4kdye0oz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.valueDecimals

Answer (score 0):

If `this.calories[0].calories` is a number, you can use `Math.round`:

```
this.grapcalories = Math.round(this.calories[0].calories);
```

If `this.calories[0].calories` is an array of numbers, you can use `Math.round` combined with `map`:

```
this.grapcalories = this.calories[0].calories.map((cal) => Math.round(cal));
```

If you want it to be two decimals

```
this.grapcalories = this.calories[0].calories.map((cal) => cal.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: There are 30 values in the decalared varibale as an array, so its not changing instead showing null

Comment: In another array i got dates as like this format "2019-07-31T09:56:11.912Z"
 how can i make it to 2019-07-31 ?

Comment: @stephen you can use the `DatePipe` in your template, or do `const date = new Date("2019-07-31T09:56:11.912Z")` and parse it from there